# Ways to select a group or individual items from fair sized list

Tags: multi-selection, grouped-list

Let say I have a list of 20 Employees of a company and they are grouped into a handful (5) Departments. I need to select one or more Employees or Departments. What are some approaches to do this?

Auto suggestion / Typeahead type field comes to mind, but I haven't really seen any examples where they show grouped data and allow the group to be selected.

Comment: What do you need to do with the data when you select it? Does it populate some other field? Just display it visually? Submit it somewhere?

Comment: Submit it somewhere. It's used for filtering search results. The system allows complex search queries. So multiple of these selections may be used. Each one operates independently from one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up asking the dev to build a multi-select typeahead.

We put in icons to depict the different level in the hierarchy. If the group is selected, the associated icon is shown so the user knows the group is selected.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

It allows you to group within a selection, and select more than one employee from the same or different groups.  I don't see built in support to select all from a single group with one click, but that could likely be worked in.

Comment: Thanks Will Cole! And there's http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/ for a non-jQuery solution.